# loading music in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a media player in Java. I have already created the GUI, now I need to load a song.
I used AudioPlayer and it doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
AudioPlayer audioP = AudioPlayer.player;
AudioStream audioS;
AudioData audioD;
ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null;
audioS = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("file:TheDragonBornComes.wav"));
audioD = audioS.getData();
loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(audioD);
audioP.start(loop);
```

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:TheDragonBornComes.wav
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
at medalmedia.MedalMedia.main(MedalMedia.java:26)
```

**EDIT:** I've changed the location of the file and the last error has been solved. However, there's a new one:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: could not create AudioData object
```

Comment: What line gives the 'could not create AudioData object' error? `audioS.getData()`? Can you print the rest of the stack trace?

Comment: I think you need to initiate/declare the AudioStream and AudioData. The error is related to AudioData.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) By `AudioPlayer` DYM `sun.audio.AudioPlayer`?!?  The J2SE has offered Java Sound since ***1.3.***

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the absolute path name. something like . `c://music//yourfilename.wav`

OR try this:

```
 audioS = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("./TheDragonBornComes.wav"));
```

Comment: Well i changed the song's location and gave it an absolute path name, the last error has been solved there's a new one:Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: could not create AudioData object